# Why are my Snort logs empty?

Tags: macos, homebrew, snort

I am running macOS Sierra 10.12.3

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.12.3
BuildVersion:   16D32
```

I have installed snort using [homebrew](https://brew.sh)

```
$ brew install snort
$ brew ls --versions snort
snort 2.9.9.0
```

I am running snort and with a *user* config file, `-s` syslog switch, and a tcpdump-file

```
$ sudo snort -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -s -r tcpdump.pcap
```

my `/etc/snort/snort.conf` file has the following *output* settings:

```
output alert_syslog: LOG_AUTH LOG_ALERT
```

When I execute,a blank file gets created at `/var/log/snort/snort.log.1489953549`

I know that my rules are working, because if I execute snort with an alert-mode of *fast*

```
$ sudo snort -c /etc/snort/snort.conf -A fast -r tcpdump.pcap
```

a new **blank** `/var/log/snort/snort.log.1489954258` is created, but a `/var/log/snort/alert` log file is also created, which contains the correct alert outputs.

I have seen [others](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2090342) run into this issue because of permissions, but I don't believe that is my problem given that I am running snort as `sudo` and it is able to write to the `alert` log just fine.

I also **do not** have `$NO_PACKET_LOG` as far as I can tell. [reference](https://www.snort.org/faq/my-snort-log-is-an-empty-file-what-could-be-the-cause)

It looks like brew installed some default snort config files under `/usr/local/etc/snort`, but I don't think that these are affecting me because I am using the `-c` switch to supply a *user* config file.

**DISCLAIMER:** This is my first time using snort, so it could be something very obvious that I am missing. Any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**
Use `tcpdump`, `snort`, `tshark`, or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) to read snort log files ([how to view snort log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477081/how-to-view-snort-log-files))

```
$ sudo tcpdump -r snort.log.1489953549
```

---

My *empty* log file was never actually empty (note file sizes from `ls`)

```
$ ls -ltr /var/log/snort/
-rw-------  1 root  admin   56018718 Mar 19 15:03 snort.log.1489954258
-rw-------  1 root  admin   56018718 Mar 19 15:11 snort.log.1489953549
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin   70202224 Mar 19 15:11 alert
```

Snort log files must be read using the correct application

What type of file is it?

```
$ sudo file snort.log.1489953549
snort.log.1489953549: tcpdump capture file (little-endian) - version 2.4 (Ethernet, capture length 1514)
```

Read the file with `tcpdump`

```
$ sudo tcpdump -r snort.log.1489954258
06:54:16.654692 IP 192.168.5.81.amt-blc-port > 100.100.100.212.6667: Flags [P.], seq 1304973037:1304973067, ack 1425084530, win 8011, options [nop,nop,TS val 14215752 ecr 2196036272], length 30
...
```

Comment: Note that if your are using unified2 output plugin, `snort.log.*` files could also be `unified2`. Then you must use `u2spewfoo` to open them.